# How to load multiple data asynchronously in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I am making an iOS app using SwiftUI. The app will have a lot of images to show in the views. The images are stored on the cloud in a hierarchical structure. I am trying a way to load each of the images asynchronously. The goals I want to achieve include:

1. Each image can load asynchronously and independently.
2. The quantity and the addresses of the images are part of the metadata saved on the cloud and need to be loaded from the cloud first before loading the image data.
3. Image loading should not not block UIs in the main thread, i.e. users can still swipe or press buttons while images are loading.
4. While an image is loading, its placeholder shows a progress view.

I have tried with the following (simplified) code:

```swift
@MainActor // <-- Need this to avoid the warning
class Metadata: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoaded = false // <-- warning if w/o @MainActor: Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed

    var images: [ImageData] = []
    
    func load() async {
        // Load metadata from cloud...
        images.append(ImageData())
        images.append(ImageData())
        images.append(ImageData())
        
        sleep(1) // To simulate loading

        isLoaded = true
    }
}

@MainActor // <-- Need this to avoid the warning
class ImageData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoaded = false // <-- warning if w/o @MainActor: Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed
    
    var data: String = "N/A" // image data or payload

    func load() async {
        // Load image data from cloud...
        data = "Image data is loaded."
        
        let us = Int.random(in: 1000000..<3000000) // 1 to 3 sec
        usleep(UInt32(us))  // To simulate loading
        
        isLoaded = true
    }
}
```

and the views:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var metadata: Metadata = Metadata()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if metadata.isLoaded {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<metadata.images.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        ImageView(image: metadata.images[i])
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await metadata.load()
        }
    }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var image: ImageData
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if image.isLoaded {
                Text(image.data)
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await image.load()
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions:**

1. Not adding `@MainActor` allows the view to load each images asynchronously. However, I got the warning message
   `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`  and sometimes not all the loadings complete.
2. Adding `@MainActor` fixes the warnings but all the loadings run on the main thread so it takes a very long time to finish loading all the images. Also, user's interactions will be blocked.
3. I have also considered using `AsyncImage`, but also want to find a generic solution for all types of data not limited to images.

Is there a good way to handle this kind of scenario? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@MainActor` and using `DispatchQueue.main.async { isLoaded = true }` in your `ImageData`. Note the sleep methods you use probably block the main thread,
 use something else, eg Thread.sleep(...)

Comment: Thank you. Removing `@MainActor` + using `DispatchQueue.main.async { isLoaded = true }` does solve my problem. 
I wonder if it's necessary not to use sync `sleep`? Removing `@MainActor` should make `Metadata` and `ImageData` work in other threads so they should not block the main thread?

Comment: @kang Do not edit your Question to include a solution that provides an Answer. If you want to add that information, put it in the Answer field, not the Question field.

Comment: If you wish to use async/await syntax (which is definitely preferable), you need to maintain a _Task Group_ to which you can add the downloading of an image as a Task. That is how you perform multiple Tasks simultaneously. Watch any of the introductory concurrency videos for more info. You should probably configure an Actor to help you with this.

Comment: I added the updated code to the answer field, and thanks for the pointer, @matt.

Answer (score -2):

Per @workingdogsupportukraine 's suggestion, the following changes solve my problem

```swift
class Metadata: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoaded = false

    var images: [ImageData] = []
    
    func load() async {
        // Loading metadata from cloud...
        images.append(ImageData())
        images.append(ImageData())
        images.append(ImageData())
        
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000)
        } catch {}

         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.isLoaded = true
         }
        // or
        // Task { @MainActor in
        //     self.isLoaded = true
        // }
    }
}

class ImageData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoaded = false
    
    var data: String = "N/A"

    func load() async {
        // Loading image data from cloud...
        data = "Image data is loaded."
        
        do {
            let sec = Int.random(in: 1..<5)
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(sec) * 1_000_000_000)
        } catch {}

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isLoaded = true
        }
        // or
        // Task { @MainActor in
        //     self.isLoaded = true
        // }
    }
}
```